# Need help to read a algorithm/code

Tags: algorithm

How much does this algorithm return? Isn't it 1 as left[x] doesn't have children?

`NIL` = no children
`left[x]` = left child
`right[x]` = right child

LEAVES is the name of the algorithm

```
if (x = nil) then
return 0
else if left[x] = nil then
return 1
else
return Leaves(left[x]) + Leaves(right[x])
end if
```

[image]

Comment: Let's add image here... Without any filedroppers.

Comment: Don't have enough reputations

Comment: So let's see, without going to filedropper... You're claiming that x != nil, but left[x] = nil? Then yeah, it returns 1. Doesn't seem complicated. Why are you asking?

Comment: This algorithm seems weird. No check on the right child...

Comment: It should be 3 not 1

Comment: Should return Leaves[left] + Leaves[right] + 1 to count the leaves.

Comment: So it should return 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you want the algorithm to return the number of leaves in the tree. In that case, if a node is equal to `NIL` then the node is a leaf. Thus the algorithm should be:

```
def Leaves(x):
    if(NotANode(x)):
        return 0
    if(x==nil):
        return 1
    return Leaves(left[x]) + Leaves(right[x])
```

NOTE: I like to use python-like formatting for pseudocode/descriptions of algorithms. Hope you do not mind :) Also note that you did not mention what `left[x]` is if `x` is missing only the right child (or vice versa). I assumed that it returned a non-node value and used the made up function `NotANode` to account for it.

### Possible Explanation

Based on how you asked this question I am guessing that this algorithm was given to you and you do not think that it is correct. Is it possible that you do not understand it's purpose?

Normally in programming `nil` or `NULL` is used to represent an "empty" object. So the first line `if x = nil` checks to see if x `x` is really a node! If it is not then it returns `0` which (assuming the purpose of `Leaves` is to count the number of leaves in the tree) is correct behavior.

Next we check if the left child of `x` exists. If it does not then we return 1. The only way this line makes sense is if we can assume that every node fills it's left child first, as then not having a left child means you do not have a right child either and so you are a leaf node (hence the result of 1).

Finally if you *do* have a left child then the given node is *not* a leaf and so we must look to it's child subtrees and count their leaves for the answer.

Review the origin of this algorithm to make sure you understand the constraints of the problem and let me know if you need more help :)